# Как получить символ utf8 из std::string?

Tags: c++

Допустим есть std::string.
Кодировка utf8. Значит один реальный символ, может кодироваться несколькими типами char(1-4).
Как в цикле определить:

1. Где начинается этот реальный символ, где заканчивается?
2. Получить сам этот символ в wchar_t?

.

```
std::string utf8_text = "Здесь лежит utf8";
wchar_t symbol; 
for(auto IT = utf8_text.begin(); IT != utf8_text.end(); IT++)
{
    unsigned char symbol= *IT;
    if(symbol>225){}
}
```

Comment: Для примера, на C# такое делается следующим образом:

    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    foreach (var c in str) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я думаю, что Вы прекрасно понимаете, что условие symbol>255 будет всегда ложно, если тип char - один байт. Но допишем программу и распечатаем вывод

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string utf8_text = "Здесь лежит utf8";
    wchar_t symbol; 
    for(auto IT = utf8_text.begin(); IT != utf8_text.end(); IT++)
    {
      unsigned char symbol= *IT;
      cout << hex << (int) symbol << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод будет таким

```
d0 97 d0 b4 d0 b5 d1 81 d1 8c 20 d0 bb d0 b5 d0 b6 d0 b8 d1 82 20 75 74 66 38
```

Заметили кучу d0 и d1? Правильно. Это это один из признаков, что в utf есть кириллица (точнее - для двухбайтовых кодировок). Теперь самое время сходить на wikipedia и почитать о том, как на низком уровне реализован [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Я пересказывать не буду. Скажу только, что нужно читать первый байт, и считаем слева на право единички до первого нуля. Это и будет ответом, сколько байт нужно прочитать. Смотрим d0 => **11**010000, два байта. Один байт мы уже прочитали, значит нужно дочитать ещё один. В всех последующих байтах будет одна первая единичка и ноль. Следующий байт - 97 => **10**010111. Готово, теперь вычленяем результат

**110**10000 **10**010111 => 100 0001 0111 => 0417(hex)

идем на любой сайт с [юникодными таблицами](http://unicode-table.com/ru/) и вбиваем код символа для поиска - [U+0417](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=U%2B0417) и видим - "Кириллическая заглавная буква зэ" - что соответствует действительности.

Что бы не делать это "вручную", можно использовать библиотек codecvt, но ее как то плохо реализовали в gcc/clang - мне не удалось завести нормально.

Comment: я не знаток, а нельзя ли тупо загнать все в wstring и пробежаться форичем for (wchar_t t :wstring) ?

Comment: @b2soft: Проблема заключается в том, что «загнать» не так уж и просто.

Comment: понял, спасибо

Comment: Понял. А мне всегда почему то казалось, что проверка идёт на значение unsigned char, то есть если больше допустим 225 то символ не один, если второй больше 225 то три символа и.т.д, а потом на основе этих сумм получается символ. Ну мне проще действительно преобразовать в wstring, а потом вытащить, чем искать и внедрять таблицы соответствия символов или доп библиотеки. 

Вот так MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,..)